# Python + Access via pyodbc: Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile), etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-access, pyodbc, comtypes

I am trying to automate some Python/Access interactions using Python 3.5.2 and Canopy. I am currently trying to use tkinter to get a user defined file name. This is then used to create a new Python database (deleting an existing one if necessary). However, I am unable to connect to the existing database.

```
import pyodbc #connect to Access
import os #allows us to do some directory changing and file work
import tkinter #lets us ask the user for a directory
from tkinter import filedialog
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
 #for creating the mdb
root = tkinter.Tk()

mdbPath = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(parent=root, title='Create a filename for your output database', defaultextension=".mdb")

mdbPath = mdbPath.replace("/","\\")
root.destroy()
if os.path.exists(mdbPath):
    os.remove(mdbPath)   
print('selected file')
DBEngine = CreateObject('DAO.DBEngine.120')

dbLangGeneral = ';LANGID=0x0409;CP=1252;COUNTRY=0'
db = DBEngine.CreateDatabase(mdbPath, dbLangGeneral, 64)
db.Close()

connAccess = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ={'+mdbPath+'};'
    )

cnxnAccess = pyodbc.connect(connAccess)
cursAccess = cnxnAccess.cursor()
```

As far as I can tell, everything works fine until I try to call pyodbc.connect(connAccess), and I am unsure why. I've tried looking at some related questions (e.g., ["General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) ..." from Access ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244425/general-error-unable-to-open-registry-key-temporary-volatile-from-access)) but can't understand how they're related.

Based on [Create new Access database and tables using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995802/create-new-access-database-and-tables-using-python) my best guess is that I need to release the assets after creating db (previously newdb) in some way. (e.g., [Create new Access database and tables using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995802/create-new-access-database-and-tables-using-python#comment67345294_40004454)) However, I cannot seem to send any commands that actually "release" this database. Even using db = Null or del db doesn't appear to do it.

Edit: Adjusted code to my current working code. Changed tags to reflect my use of comtypes instead of com32.
Edit 2: Slightly adjusted code. Added another line of explanation of what I've tried.

Comment: If you're only using `win32com` to create the database file then you might find it easier to just use my free [msaccessdb](https://github.com/gordthompson/msaccessdb) Python module to do that.

Comment: @GordThompson thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I need to distribute this code amongst users of a variety of skill levels, so I'm restricted (or restricting myself) to packages available through Canopy, which is the general python editor for the group.

Comment: Have you tried `newdb.Close` immediately after you call `CreateDatabase`?

Comment: @GordThompson Yes I've also added db.Quit(), setting the 4 db/access elements to none, and del'ing them. No change!

Sorry for the delay - I had to run this on a different computer after updating Access for a reason I've yet to determine.